# How to close winform with TopMost=true, when another application opens on top of my app

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a C# .Net 3.5, winform (displaying graph) that needs to remain open as a front screen. I refresh the graph during the `datagridview` `RowEnter` event of the calling window. I open graph winform as `show()`, and use `TopMost = true`. Everything works fine till I open another application like Word; Graph window still remains in the front of Word.

Is there an application event gets triggered when another application opens on top of my application, when I can close the open graph screen.  Or, please let me know if you have a suggestion about the different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Form.Deactivate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx). It is raised when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form. You can use this event to [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) the form

Comment: I did use the Form.Deactivate event, but sometimes the graph closes unexpectedly when I switch between the graph and the form with the datagridview, because the Form.deactivate event gets triggered. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AGR090808 Is _the form with the datagridview_ invoked by the same application as the _graph form_?

Comment: Yes. I have a main form that opens Graph, also the main form opens a form with DG. DG and Graph communicates and refreshes the graph while Graph is open. For that reason I had to use Topmost for the graph. Thanks.

Comment: Inside the Deactivate event handler you can use various methods to find out which process is active/focused and Close the Graph form. E.g [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/GetActiveProcess.aspx) is using GetForegroundWindow function to obtain the handle of the active window

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I am using GetForegroundWindow in the Deactivate event and that is working!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't get the sense of your question. You set `TopMost=true` and the next moment you want it to hide behind another application... ????

Comment: I don't want the graph to be behind another application, I would just like to close it as soon as another application opens on top of my application.

Answer (score 0):

This solution method is 100% working, considering that the login form name is **loginForm**.

1. Simply create the following method:

   ```
   private void hideLogin()
   {
       if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["loginForm"] != null)
       {
           System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["loginForm"].Hide();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call this method through task:

   ```
   Task HideLoginTask = new Task(hideLogin); 
   HideLoginTask.Start();
   ```